# redirect a file using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

There is a way to redirect some files named for example file.php and placed into randoms spots of the webspace (web-root, inside one or more dir, etc) to mysite.com/test ?

```
Example 1:
```

I want to redirect file.php placed in root to mysite.com/test

```
Example 2:
```

I want to redirect file.php placed inside a random dir to mysite.com/test

Comment: Did you try using mod_rewrite? The second case is not clear. Do you want to redirect all files named file.php in any location?

Comment: yes i want to redirect all files named file.php in any location

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following config to redirect any URL which ends with `file.php`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /file.php$
RewriteRule file.php$ http://mysite.com/test [R,L]
```

Comment: To explain you further, please visit this link http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html.